# Problem with aligning of links

Tags: html, css

Hi, I am making this website but I don't know why these images are not aligning properly. The link for menu and about I want to do the same with contact and event but can't until I figure out the problem.

This website is for a friend and I want to make it the best it can. Please help . Thanks :)

I found a tutorial to do the hover thing from some website but can't figure out the problem.

http://themuv.com/tester123/bombay3/index.php

I guess it has something to do with positioning but what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What it is that you "want to do"? What is the expected output??

Comment: @Danny please show some actual code. Questions consisting only of links are frowned upon here, because they will lose all value to future readers when the problem is fixed.

Comment: basically the menu button and the about button can appear in a line like on the right side contact and event button without conpromising with the hover functionality

Comment: how can i show up the entire site here ??? is there any way to do it or should i just post the entire source code and css here??

Comment: Not the entire site. Just the relevant code fragment(s) that doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the `line-height` css command. It makes your entire site look terrible, and there is absolutely no reason to put it on the entire body. line-height should be rarely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined your code and it's super strange. The main reason why those two links won't aligned inline is because you set `display: block` to this element. I guess you use this css attribute so that it match the width and height that you've specified. And I see you use a css background image just for those two (actually) textual links.

Here is my suggestion:

1. Use simple text instead of background image.
2. Remove that totally
   unnecessary  element as the parent of those two links (it's not
   semantically right anyway)

Here is the code

```
<a href="#">Menu</a> | <a href="#">About</a>
```

set the css like this

```
a{ color: #fff; } a:hover{color: #000; }
```

It should be so very-very simple, but you make it so complicated dude ;)